# How to make equations selectable in PDFs exported from Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2007

I'm working in Microsoft Office Word 2007. I exported a document to PDF, but the equations aren't selectable, only the text.

It looks like this, if I select a sentence:

[image]

How can I export my document to PDF, to make the equations selectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, do the following

1. In Word, save your document using the Save As function
2. Select PDF as the file type.
3. After you select PDF as the file type, select the options dialog.
4. In the options dialog, select Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded.
5. Click OK.
6. Save your PDF.  You should now be able to select the text in your equations.

[image]

Comment: did this do anything for you?